# Развернул бота на pythonanywhere, но он не запускается

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver, pythonanywhere

Написал скрипт для инстаграм бота, загрузил его на pythonanywhere, при запуске выдает ошибку

```
ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version
```

Выдает эту ошибку из-за строки:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Для установки использую следующую библиотеку:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно исправить, чтобы заработало

Comment: Очевидно что для использования `ChromeDriver` нужен `Chrome`, которого, собственно, и нету на `pythonanywhere`

Comment: Какую версию питона и версию `webdriver_manager` вы используете?

Comment: @0dminnimda, 3.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы `Selenium` смог заработать, ему нужен браузер. Если мы хотим использовать Chrome, тогда нам нужно его [скачать](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Но, на PythonAnywhere уже установлен `chromedriver`, если просто хотите запустить с помощью установленной версии, используйте [этот туториал](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/)

И тут появляется `webdriver-manager` ...
Читая исходный код, я не уверен, баг ли это, вводящее ли в заблуждение описание или просто пакет ещё не доделан ...,
т.к. чтобы заработала версия 3.4.3?, надо чтобы на устройстве уже был установлен  Chrome. (пакет, его видимо не находит)

Я бы вам порекомендовал пока скачать браузер самостоятельно, если вам нужна конкретная версия.

Но если уж вам так хочется использовать ту библиотеку, то вот для вас решение для выше указанной версии:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

import requests

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType, chrome_version, validate_response
from webdriver_manager.driver import ChromeDriver


def new_init(self, name, version, os_type, url, latest_release_url,
             chrome_type=ChromeType.GOOGLE):
    super(ChromeDriver, self).__init__(name, version, os_type, url,
                                       latest_release_url)
    self.chrome_type = chrome_type


@property
def new_browser_version(self):
    try:
        return chrome_version(self.chrome_type)
    except Exception:
        return None


def get_latest_release_version(self):
    resp = requests.get(self._latest_release_url)
    validate_response(resp)
    return resp.text.rstrip()


ChromeDriver.__init__ = new_init
ChromeDriver.browser_version = new_browser_version
ChromeDriver.get_latest_release_version = get_latest_release_version

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Второй вариант - скачать более раннюю версию - около 1.5

Ещё к слову, чтобы запустить `selenium` на pythonanyehere и не использовать рекомендованные `--headless`, посмотрите на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28188009/12141949)

---

Но, в итоге, у меня не получилось запустить никакими другими методами, кроме рекомендуемого, т.е.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
try:
    browser.get("https://www.google.com")
    print("Page title was '{}'".format(browser.title))
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: @Михаил если вам помог или понравится этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers); Да и просто за старания можно))

Comment: @Михаил извините, что так настойчиво прошу, но если вы проголосовали за ответ, то вы ещё не [приняли его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Я буду очень благодарен, если вы это сделаете. (надо нажать на галочку)